# How do I view this serialized xml content?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

When I send a specific remote query I'm interested in into my application I pull back an xml document that looks like this:

```xml
<content>
    <id>694</id>
    <serializedContent>
        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
    </serializedContent>
</content>
```

From the tool's documentation about the query:

> [GET] /task/{taskId}/content
>   Gets the task content from a task identified by the given task id
>   **Returns** a JaxbContent with the content of the task. The taskId component of the URL must conform to the following regex: [0-9]+

What I wonder is: what exactly am I looking at within the 'serializedContent' tag, and how do I go about deserializing it?

Comment: It could be a Java object, a file, whatever other thing it may be serialized... Please provide more info about the producer of this service apart of the documentation e.g. which technology uses to provide this data?

Comment: Don't have much info about it, hence the issue. So I guess there's no way of generically deserializing whatever it is then..

Comment: Just fyi, you're in luck because Blaise Doughan knows his chit. He's the resident JAXB expert on this site, and I've never seen him give a wrong answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The serialized content is most like base6Binary if you are processing it yourself you can use the `DatatypeConverter` class as follows:

```
byte[] binary = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(string);
```

If you want to map this to JAXB you could do so with thr following class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Content {

    private int id;

    private byte[] serializedContent;

}
```

Comment: @CanadianCoder - I'm happy to help a fellow Canadian.